# iphone table view - button inside table cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I have created a button and placed it inside a table cell:

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
...
[cell.aSubView addSubview:btn];
```

The button shows up in the table cell, but tapping it highlights and selects the entire cell. How can I just get the button to be selected on its own?

Comment: What is that aSubView.. Why cant you use [cell.contentView addSubView:btn];

Comment: Because aSubView is a container UIView in the xib file that the cell is built from.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `cell.aSubView`? You should go with the `contentView` property. From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> If you want to customize cells by
>   simply adding additional views, you
>   should add them to the content view so
>   they will be positioned appropriately
>   as the cell transitions into and out
>   of editing mode.

Comment: The cells are custom xib files, and aSubView is a container UIView in the xib file.

Answer (score 0):

Set your cell's `selectionStyle` property to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.
Make sure `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` handles the tap on the cell properly (e.g. ignores it if that is what you want).

Comment: If I set the selectionStyle to None, the cell isn't selectable. I need the cell to respond on selection OUTSIDE of the button. But if the button is tapped, i do not want the cell to select. I just want the button selector to be called.